# Can java.util.MissingResourceException occur after Java Heapspace error?

Tags: java, classloader, heap-memory

We get Java heap space error in our Tomcat application which is expected. But after that we see a lot of java.util.MissingResourceException occurring frequently. Is there any relation between java.util.MissingResourceException and Out of memory - Java heap space error?

Comment: Of course. It could be *caused* by the heap space error.

Comment: The heap space error is expected? Are you serious? It's like saying "one of the tyres blew up while driving on the highway, which was expected. the car spun out of control after that, could there be a connection?". Sorry, but the heap space error tells you something is going horribly wrong. How do you expect everything to be there after the system tells you it doesn't have enough heap space to run properly?

Comment: We know the reasons for the heap space issue. But we do not know why MissingResourceException occurs many times after the heap space issue. Wanted to know if there is any direct link and reason for this exception occurring immediately after heap space error.